# Finding bounds for eigenvalues of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $A = [a_{ij}]_{N \times N}$. Suppose matrix is nonsingular so we can find eigenvalues and let $\sigma(A)$ denote the spectral radius. That is $\sigma = \max |\lambda|$. Finding this usually is hard task, so one may need to estimate it. One nice result from linear algebra is Gershgorin circle theorem that states that if $\rho_s  = \sum_{j=1, j \neq s }^N |a_{sj} |$ that is $\rho_s$ is the sum of off diagonal elements of row s of matrix. The theorem then says that for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$ we can always find $s$ so that $| \lambda - a_{ss} | \leq \rho_s $.

My question: are  there more results like Gerschorin that let us estimate eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues are roots of a polynomial with coefficients that are polynomial in matrix entries. There are theorems that bound the roots of polynomials in general (one that comes to mind is $|z|<(A+1)^n$ where $A$ is maximal absolute value of polynomial coefficients and $n$ its deg). Those bounds are really weak though.